# Identify color of palm lines from image - need more than Canny

Tags: opencv, image-recognition

I'm trying to identify the lines in palm images and extract the color.   So far I can identify edges, but this isn't the full palm line itself - and the edge may be either inside or outside of the 'palm line'.   I want to identify those dark pixels that define the palm line.

So far I've had the most success using opencv and the Canny edge detection algorithm.   My code (similar to their example):

```
int lowThreshold;       // vary this using a slider
int ratio = 3;
int kernel_size = 3;
Mat cvSource;           // source image, BGR
Mat cvSourceGray;       // source, Gray space
Mat cvCanny;            // edge detection via Canny

cvtColor( cvSource, cvSourceGray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
blur( cvSourceGray, cvSourceGray, cv::Size(3,3) );  // Reduce noise with a kernel 3x3
Canny( cvSourceGray, cvCanny, lowThreshold, lowThreshold*ratio, kernel_size );
```

The problem I'm running into is that, once I have Canny tuned for edge detection, it gives me an edge that is one pixel wide, i.e., not the palm line, but the edge (detection) of the palm line.   I'm not getting edges on both sides of the line - just one   And that edge isn't necessarily on the palm line - it may be outside the line so the color varies to either the light or dark colors of the palm - as you can see in the image following - both a sample image and two Canny outputs - different 'lowThreshold's are shown.

I have followed this up with findContours - which works, but is essentially using the Canny output so it's not adding anything to this problem.

I'm hoping someone could give me ideas on how to better detect a palm line - where the palm line is defined as the actual pixels on the line/inside of the line area so I can grab the color.

Thanks!

[image: Palm image]
<sub>(source: [radioshowlinks.com](http://www.radioshowlinks.com/f/pics/B2.png))</sub>
[image: Canny output 1]
<sub>(source: [radioshowlinks.com](http://www.radioshowlinks.com/f/pics/Canny-B2-9.png))</sub>
[image: Canny output 2]

Comment: The answer I came up with is to use the output of Canny to feed into neighborhood processing.   Running a 3x3 cell across each pixel the resulting inner pixel would be a one if and only if (a) inside the 3x3 grid there was an 'edge' from Canny; and (b) the pixel was the darkest of any within the 3x3 community.    Turns out that this also needed to be run for several 'generations' in order to circle in on a good result.    Net net - works fine!

Comment: I'm trying to deal with a similar problem now. I need to detect all the most prominent palm lines http://answers.opencv.org/question/37527/detecting-palm-lines/